# Remove Polyline tool from drawing manager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove PolyLine drawing tool from Google maps API V3, Sorry if this is a silly question. I'm new to this, I've searched everywhere before asking it in here. Thank You.

I've added the image below for more clarity. I want to remove that tool from the options.

[image]

I'm using the below code to initialize the `drawingManager`

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    },
    drawingModes: [
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    //google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
  ],

    markerOptions: {
        draggable: false,
        label: ""
    },

    // polylineOptions: {
    //     editable: false,
    // },

    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    map: map
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your posted code: `ReferenceError: polyOptions is not defined`.

You have a typo in your `DrawingManager` constructor, `drawingModes` belongs in the `drawingControlOptions` object (per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawingmanager_options)) your code:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    },
    drawingModes: [
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    //google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
  ],
```

should be:

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        //google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
      ],
    },
```

(note the position of the closing `}` for `drawingControlOptions`)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x5u172bw/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&libraries=drawing">
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        //google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
      ],
    },
    markerOptions: {
      draggable: false,
      label: ""
    },

    /* polyOptions is not defined... */
    // rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    // circleOptions: polyOptions,
    // polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    map: map
  });


  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Drawing Tools</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```